# Javascript Validation On display block elements

Tags: javascript

Friends I had a form with various fields including 4 gender radio buttons. Onclick it will open respective div. I want to validate elements in the respective open div. Here is the code

```
<form action="" method="post" name="signup_form" id="signup_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="javascript: return validate_signup(this);">    
    <div>
        Name
        <input type="text" name="mdl_fname" id="mdl_fname" value="" />
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="sex" id="male" value="Male" onclick="ShowHidediv();" />Male
        <br />
        <input type="radio" name="sex" id="female" value="Female" onclick="ShowHidediv2();" />Female
        <br />
        <input type="radio" name="sex" id="transmale" value="Transgender Male" onclick="ShowHidediv();" />Transgender Male
        <br />
        <input type="radio" name="sex" id="transfemale" value="Transgender Female" onclick="ShowHidediv2();" />Transgender Female
    </div>

    <div id="dtls">
        <p>Select Gender to View Details</p>
    </div>    
    <!-- female content starts -->
    <div id="female-content" style="display:none; border:1px solid #FF0000; width:300px; padding:20px; margin:20px 0px;">
        <select name="f-hgt" id="f-hgt">
            <option selected="selected" value="">--- Female ---</option>
            <option value="Hi">Hi</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <!-- female content ends -->

    <!-- male content starts -->
    <div id="male-content" style="display:none; border:1px solid #FF0000; width:300px; padding:20px; margin:20px 0px;">

        <input type="text" name="m-hgt" id="m-hgt" value="" />
        <!-- 
    <select id="m-hgt" name="m-hgt">
        <option selected="selected" value="">--- Male ---</option>
        <option value="Hello">Hello</option>
    </select>
    -->
    </div>
    <!-- male content ends -->    
    <div>
        <input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do :

```
$('#male').on('click', function() {
    $('#male-content').show();
}
```

**EDIT**
if you really want to use your function here is how to do it :

```
var ShowHidediv = function() {
    $('#male-content').show();
}
```

Comment: in jquery `show()` and `hide()` methods toggles the `display` css attribute between none and it's default value

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to toggle the display mode, but you could try this. It will give you a nice transition:

```
$('#male').on('click', function() {
   $('#male-content').fadeToggle('slow');
}
```